# React dynamic image rendering problem with local images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, express, fs

I want to visit a webpage, download the images on that page, and then render the images on my React UI.

After I visit the page, I visit each image source and download the image into my shared `public` folder.

As each file writes like this on the backend (Express):

```
fs.writeFile("client/public/assets/" + imageName + ".png",
  await viewSource.buffer(), function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
})
```

on the client side, I am dynamically rendering React img elements like this:

```
  return (
    <img
      {...element.attribs}
      src={'./assets/' + imageName}
    ></img>
  )
```

The problem is, the page refreshes every single time I save a new picture file to `public/assets`. This leaves me with a blank UI because my page refreshes after every picture is saved. How do I fix this?

Comment: So you want to download all the images, and once that's done, render the react app? Are you looping through your /assets folder and rendering everything in there?

Comment: how does your client-side know there's a change in the server?

Comment: @georgedum yes that is what i would like to do. i save the downloaded files locally one by one, then send a response from the back end. my front end then picks up the response and then looks for the image by name in my /assets folder. the name is set as `imageName` and it equals to the file name and it is set as the path in the image element as the source.

Comment: @nick I am calling an endpoint to my express backend and then receiving the response on the client side. the endpoint logic contains visiting the page, and downloading the images and saving them locally. and then sends a 200 response.

Comment: From the code you posted above, there could be an async problem, is there any chance that your express server returned the imageName while the fs.writeFile hasn't finished? open the chrome devtool and check the response from ./assets/+image name, Consider `writeFileSync`

Comment: Thanks @nick for helping. I tried `writeFileSync` as you said and I still face the same issue.

I'm not able to check dev tools for the response because the page keeps refreshing every time the picture is downloaded :(

Comment: @RJK Can you try to click 'Preserve log' in Chrome's network panel? then redirecting doesn't wipe your network history

Comment: i never knew that @nick thanks! i clicked Preserve log. It looks like the page is outright refreshing every time I write a file to the shared `public` folder. So it doesn't even get a chance to get the response :O

Comment: I wonder why my page would refresh when I point my img src to the path in my `public` shared folder?

Comment: @RJK Did you have your problem solved?

Comment: @nick, yes I had to make sure I cleared the contents of the directory after I get done using it. otherwise it kept updating the files already in the directory and reset the state each time.